# Illegal string offset 'id'

Tags: php, session

I'm working in a login system on my website and I'm stuck.
Here my code

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['pseudo']))
    {
        $pseudo = Securise($_SESSION['pseudo']);
        try
        {
            $sql = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE pseudo = '".$pseudo."' LIMIT 1");

        }catch (Exception $e){
            die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
        $row_count = $sql->rowCount();

        if($row_count > 0)
            {
                $req = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE pseudo = '".$pseudo."' LIMIT 1");
                $user = $req->fetchColumn();
                $up = $DB->query("UPDATE users SET last_ip = '".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."' WHERE id = '".$user['id']."'");
            }
            else {
            session_destroy();
            Redirect("".$lien."");
            exit();
            }
    }
```

I get an error at the following line

```
$up = $DB->query("UPDATE users SET last_ip = '".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."' WHERE id = '".$user['id']."'");
```

I can't figure out why Php give me a
"Warning: Illegal string offset 'id"

Comment: remove single quotes before and after the `$user['id']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line :

```
$user = $req->fetchColumn();
```

to:

```
$user = $req->fetch();
```

Then you can get user id by:

```
$user['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

[`fetchColumn` returns a single value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php), not an array, so you can't access it like an associative array.

If `id` is your first column, you can just use `$user` instead of `$user['id']`. Note that `SELECT *` is usually not a good idea, because changes to your database can easily break your application logic if you are depending on certain columns being in a certain order.

Comment: Minor nitpick: You *can* access strings based on numeric offsets, but it will not do what the OP wants, though.

Comment: That's true; added clarification ("like an associative array").